# $(\forall x \in D) (P(x)) \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)(x\in D \implies P(x)) $. how are two the same?

Tags: logic

Assuming all the variables are naturals, why are those two equal?
I don't get how $\implies$ is introduced in the latter equation: 
 $(∀x)(x∈D \implies P(x))$

Thanks.

Comment: In the latter equation, you're looking at all $x$, but all you want is that $P(x)$ occurs whenever $x\in D$. I think that's where $\implies$ comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter Smith notes, most commonly

$$\forall x \in D.\ P(x) \quad \text{ is defined as }\quad\forall x.\ x \in D \implies P(x).$$

However, should this be unsatisfactory explanation for you, there is alternative argument below.

---

First
\begin{align}
\mathtt{true} \implies P(x) \quad \text{ is equivalent to } \quad P(x), \\
\mathtt{false} \implies P(x) \quad \text{ is equivalent to } \quad \mathtt{true}.
\end{align}
Hence,

\begin{align}
\forall x \in D.\ P(x) &\quad\text{ is equivalent to }\quad \forall x \in D.\ x \in D \implies P(x), \\
\forall x \notin D.\ \mathtt{true} &\quad\text{ is equivalent to }\quad \forall x \notin D.\ x \in D \implies P(x).
\end{align}
Then, if we join them with
$$P'(x) = \begin{cases}P(x) & \text{for }x \in D \\ \mathtt{true} & \text{for }x \notin D\end{cases}$$

we get

$$\forall x.\ P'(x) \quad\text{ is equivalent to }\quad \forall x.\ x \in D \implies P(x).$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: No, it doesn't help. The straightforward answer is that  $(\forall x \in D)(P(x)$  is usually just *defined* as a slick abbreviation for  $(\forall x)(x\in D \implies P(x))$.

Comment: @PeterSmith Usually it is defined this way, but it does not have to be, e.g. if the universe is not a set,  perhaps there is some specific semantic to it. Of course, point taken, this is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what the $\forall x\in D. P(x)$ notation is defined to mean.

Comment: This is, of course, exactly right!

Answer (score 2):

If you interpret both D and P as sets, both of them say precisely that D is a subset of P.